# php: advance to next year minus 1 day

Tags: php, date

Problem: I'm using strtotime to advance by 364 days in the future, but I'm getting troubles with leap years.

Example: today is January 20, 2012 -
I need PHP to compute for me the timestamp of January 19, 2013.

If I simply add

strtotime("+364 days");

I correctly get January 18, 2013 - but for the code I'm writing I don't need to consider leap years and thus I expect to obtain January 19, 2013.

Any quick and dirty way to do this?

Comment: `strtotime("+1 year") - 86400` or `strtotime("+1 year -1 day")`?

Comment: surely this is clear to me, I was wondering of a quick method to determine when I need to subtract 1 day (and thus verify if there's a February 29 in the range)

Comment: `$leapyear = $year % 4 == 0 && ($year % 100 != 0 || $year % 400 == 0)`

Comment: forgive me, question wasn't that clear. I knew before posting how do determine leap years and how to advance by 1 year minus 1 day. The fact is that only considering if current year is leap isn't enough: think of: April 1, 2012 --> I need to get March 30, 2013 and advance 364 days, even if 2012 is a leap year

Comment: Then check whether you are already in March or later.

Comment: @TimWolla Or just do this: `date('L', $timestamp)==='1'`

Comment: @Sebastiano `strtotime()` takes leap years into account by itself. You don't need to do anything here. `strtotime('+1 year -1 day');` is all you need to do.

Answer (score 3):

`strtotime()` takes the leap year into account.

replace `strtotime("+364 days");` with `strtotime('+1 year -1 day');`

note: not everybody want to read a bunch of comments to get the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also try checking if the year is leap or not and then add that +/- 1 Day

```
<?php

function is_leap()
{
    $year = date('Y');
    $check = ((($year % 4) == 0) && ((($year % 100) != 0) || (($year %400) == 0)));
    return $check;
}

$year = (is_leap()) : strtotime("+365 days") ? strtotime("+364 days")

?>
```